# Cardinality query with inconsistent results

Tags: owl, protege, dlquery

I am having problems with DL Queries that are based on object property cardinality and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or there is something wrong with HermiT.

First of all, I've attached a very simple ontology which demonstrates my problem. There are only two individuals **A** and **B** and the object property *hasSomething*. **A** *hasSomething* **B** is true.

The following DL Query returns **A** as a result:

```
hasSomething min 1
```

While the query

```
hasSomething exactly 1
```

cannot be satisfied.

Does anyone have an idea why the first one works and the second doesn't?

```html
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/cg/ontologies/2015/9/untitled-ontology-3#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/cg/ontologies/2015/9/untitled-ontology-3> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/cg/ontologies/2015/9/untitled-ontology-3> rdf:type owl:Ontology .


#################################################################
#
#    Object Properties
#
#################################################################


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/cg/ontologies/2015/9/untitled-ontology-3#hasSomething

:hasSomething rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .





#################################################################
#
#    Classes
#
#################################################################


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/cg/ontologies/2015/9/untitled-ontology-3#SimpleClass

:SimpleClass rdf:type owl:Class .





#################################################################
#
#    Individuals
#
#################################################################


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/cg/ontologies/2015/9/untitled-ontology-3#A

:A rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;

   :hasSomething :B .



###  http://www.semanticweb.org/cg/ontologies/2015/9/untitled-ontology-3#B

:B rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .




###  Generated by the OWL API (version 3.5.1) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net
```

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure but I would guess this has something to do with the Open World Assumption. From what I gather cardinality is used mainly as a restriction. But in the case of a query, because of the OWA, specifying "exactly 1" does not let the reasoner know that there are no other individuals that satisfy that condition.

Comment: @KunalKhaladkar you are absolutely correct. It's because of the OWA that this cannot be inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query cannot be fulfilled because of the Open World Assumption (OWA).

From the [OWL2 Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#What_is_OWL_2.3F):

> If some fact is not present in a database, it is usually considered false (the so-called closed-world assumption) whereas in the case of an OWL 2 document it may simply be missing (but possibly true), following the **open-world assumption**.

csnyluas, who is a protegé contributor / maintainer gave the following answer:

> This is correct. Because of the open world assumption (OWA) in OWL,
>   from your assertions the reasoner cannot infer that A has no other
>   "hasSomething" relationships to other individuals than B.
>
> If you would modify your ontology to state that A is of type
>   SimpleClass, and that SimpleClass is subclass of "hasSomething exactly
>   1", then the reasoner would return A as instance of both "hasSomething
>   min 1" and "hasSomething exactly 1".